# ElasticSearch poor query performance one 100K documents dataset

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using the default dynamic mapping on ElasticSearch, and calling the search method over the Java API as follow:

```
    response = client.prepareSearch("test")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)) 
    .setFrom(0).setSize(1000).setExplain(false)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

After several optimizations on memory issues, including the heap size, disable swapping, the performance is very bad comparing with other engines. For instance, the query "Name:*" takes almost 2 minutes to perform. What can i do to improve significantly the performance? The documents are very small with almost 1 token for each field.

Comment: Do you find that non wild card searches are also slow?

Comment: Start with a normal size, say 10 instead of 1000, what does it yield?

Comment: Please update with mapping of your document. Also wildcards are not recommended way for searching.

Comment: @bhspencer Even without wild card query, the other searches are also slow, i don't have explicit mapping, i'm using the elasticsearch dynamic mapping. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @Val I really need an huge number of retrieved documents for my search, even 1k it's not enough

Comment: Why not using [scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html) instead?

Comment: @Val I can´t use because "Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data" and i need all the results at the same time. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Shalin LK After remove the wild card and replace by a match_all query the performance improve allot thank you, do you thing that a mapping can improve the performance allot on query task? i don't care about the quality of results, only the time is important.

Comment: one thing to consider is the type of hard disk your index is stored on. With a large index that cannot fit entirely in RAM HD access times make a huge impact. I saw a 10x speed up in query time when I switched to an SSD on the server.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was on the query type used. QueryStringQuery checks every single field from one document. By using a matchQuery the performance increased allot. Thanks for the helpful comments.